# How to get cornerRadius of UITextField with roundedRect style

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am injecting a UIVisualEffectView (UIBlurEffect) into a UITextField which has a roundedRect border style.

Problem is that the UIVisualEffectView is a solid rectangle and I would like it to be "clipped" by its parent. Or to apply a cornerRadius which is the same has the UITextField, but when I access this value, it is always 0.

Here is the visual thing where you can see that the UITextField has rounded corners but not the blurView:

[image: Glitch corner radius]

And here is the code:

```
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
textField.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)
blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Note: I can always set manually the cornerRadius of the blurView, but I would like a "safe" dynamic version

Comment: What about using `textField.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: @Satish Did that. Doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: My question is about getting the value dynamically not statically. Corner Radius is different on iOS 11 and iOS 10. Might as well change in the future.

Answer (score -1):

[I think the best way to set corner radius is:

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIi1u.png)

Comment: He asked about how to GET the radius. This answer also is just a link and has no additional information about how to set things up to show the information in the image.